# Spacy CLI tools not functioning

Tags: python, spacy, spacy-3

As the title says, I am unable to use the spacy cli tools. I get `No module named spacy`  error when I try to run `python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_trf`.

I was able to install the sm, md and lg models a few days ago. But now it doesnt seem to be working. I have spacy v3 installed

```
import spacy
spacy.__version__
```

gives `'3.1.2'`

running `python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_trf` gives the error. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Something is wrong with your Python setup. Try `import sys;print(sys.executable)` in Python, that's probably not the same as `which python3` in the shell. I would recommend you set up a virtualenv.

Comment: @polm23 the `sys.executable` returns  `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3` and the `which python3` returns `/usr/bin/python3` . What should I do in this case

Comment: How are you executing Python code?